# По местному обычаю (запятые)

Tags: пунктуация

Помогите, пожалуйста, расставить запятые во фразе:

"Потолки в комнатах(,) по местному обычаю(,) были прибиты поверх балок".

Поискал в нацкорпусе и только запутался. В разные годы то обособляется, то нет. А в нынешнее время - такое ощущение, что "кто как хочет, так и лопочет".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Грамота.ру посвятила этому "вводному слову" (я насчитываю два), **[статью](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_577)**, где разобраны все случаи...

Ну, вводное так вводное, обособляется, стало быть.

НО! ***"В спорных случаях решение о постановке знаков препинания при словах «по обычаю» остается за автором текста".***

> ! Не смешивать с употреблением в роли члена предложения. Слово
>   «обычай» в этом случае синонимично словам «традиция, установленное
>   правило поведения». При этом сочетание «по обычаю» может разрываться
>   характеризующим прилагательным, например: «по русскому обычаю», «по
>   старинному обычаю», «по древнему обычаю» и т. п. В этом случае
>   обособление оборота «по обычаю» не требуется.
>
> *Вдова взяла поданный ей по обычаю веничек, обмела края могильного холмика и потом поклонилась людям поясно, хотя ей это было и нелегко…*
>   Е. Евтушенко, Ардабиола. *Приступ психопатии у него прошел, он шутил,
>   по древнему русскому обычаю приободрял товарищей своих, тоже желал
>   встречи на фронте, скорой встречи, пока совсем не довели их здесь до
>   смерти.* В. Астафьев, Прокляты и убиты.
>
> Впрочем. в художественной литературе встречаются примеры обособления
>   слов «по обычаю» в значении:
>
> *В день свадьбы Левин, по обычаю (на исполнении всех обычаев строго
>   настаивали княгиня и Дарья Александровна), не видал своей невесты и
>   обедал у себя в гостинице со случайно собравшимися к нему тремя
>   холостяками…* Л. Толстой, Анна Каренина.

Это свидетельствует о

> нестрогом разграничении двух указанных выше значений. В спорных
>   случаях решение о постановке знаков препинания при словах «по обычаю»
>   остается за автором текста.

Answer (score 4):

Оборот обособляется (удобная позиция, значение уточнения):

Потолки в комнатах, **по местному обычаю**, были прибиты поверх балок.

Пояснение

Обособление зависит от структуры и распространенности оборота и предложения. Можно выделить три варианта:

1) Не обособляется в значении обстоятельства в основном сообщении:

Он протянул Шалве руку ладонью вверх **по местному обычаю**, затем быстро показал на гору, в направлении храма и приложил палец к губам, зачем-то заглянув Шалве прямо в зрачки. [Юрий Гордиенко. Мы нарисовали небо (2007)]

2) Обособляется в удобной позиции со значением уточнения:

Государь вошел в церковь, набитую толпой народа; иные целовали ему руки, другие, **по местному обычаю**, аплодировали. [Д. А. Милютин. Дневник (1877)]

3) Авторский выбор:

Стены домов ― кирпичные, саманные, деревянные ― были, **по местному обычаю**, обмазаны глиной и чисто выбелены. [Анатолий Жигулин. Черные камни (1988)]
Женни встала и вышла в кухню, а Яковлевич стал собирать со стола чай, за которым, **по местному обычаю,** всегда почти непосредственно следовала закуска. [Н. С. Лесков. Некуда (1864)]

Comment: Значит, обособление, в данном случае, как минимум дважды, сделано правильно? Спасибо!